# RemoteAttribute with Prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a container and nested viewmodels and use EditorFor to render nested viewmodels, i want to add remoteAttribute for validation to one of the properties in one viewmodel ( ConcreteViewModelA :: prop3). However, on the validation Controller action method, all i get is null.

I've tried using Validate([Bind(Prefix="item")]string prop3), but still comes back as NULL. any ideas?

```
public class SomeContainer
{
    public List<ISomethingViewModel> SomeViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteViewmodelA : ISomethingViewModel
{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
    [Remote("Validate", "RemoteValidation")]
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteViewModelB : ISomethingViewModel
{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomethingViewModel
{
    int prop1 { get; set; }
    int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model test.Models.SomeContainer

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>Begin here</p> 
    foreach (var item in Model.SomeViewModels)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => item)
    }        
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work using : public JsonResult Validate([Bind(Prefix="item")]ConcreteViewmodelA vm3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Validate([Bind(Prefix = "item")] MyViewModel model)
{
    return Json(
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Prop3), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check with firebug. Your url request looks like this `Validate?item.prop3=`

So you can do something like this to read the value

```
    public ActionResult Validate(string prop3)
    {
        string prop3Val = Request.QueryString["item.prop3"].ToString();

        //your operations with prop3Val
        return Json(prop3Val, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, firebug shows the URL as : [link]Validate?item.prop3=hello